# retrieve xml values using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to convert retrieve the info in xml tags using powershell. But this error message is what I am facing:

Select-Xml : Cannot convert value "System.Xml.XmlDocument" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as 
the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

```
[xml]$xml=
@"
<BESAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BESAPI.xsd">
<Computer Resource="https://dsw11.lab.g:52311/api/computer/549"/>
<Computer Resource="https://dsw11.lab.g:52311/api/computer/550"/>
<Computer Resource="https://dsw11.lab.g:52311/api/computer/552"/>
<Computer Resource="https://dsw11.lab.g:52311/api/computer/551"/>
</BESAPI> 
"@


#I have tried these alternatives for result, but both of them are not working

#$result = Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//Computer Resource" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
$result = Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//Computer Resource" | foreach {[pscustomobject]@($_.node.InnerXML)}
```

I want to retrieve the ID's from the computer resource. for that again,

```
foreach($str in $result)
{
$res = $str.split('/')[-1]
# next steps
}
```

I have searched a lot but not a thing is working.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: First of all, since you're passing an XML document, you need `-Xml` instead of `-Content`. Second, the nodes are actually attributes of an element, not nodes named "Computer Resource", so the XPath would be `//Computer/@Resource`. And last but not least, using `Select-Xml` for this is unnecessarily complex, since you can just use the properties PowerShell magics up for XML documents and collections: `$xml.BESAPI.Computer.Resource`

Comment: [xml]$xml = 
@"
<BESAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BESAPI.xsd">

<Computer Resource="https://dsw12tem01.cgdevlab.cg:52311/api/computer/5379">
<Property Name="Computer Name">DSW102</Property>
</Computer>
</BESAPI>

in this case, i want to retrieve computer name 'DSW12SL02'. how can that be done?

Comment: Well it can't, since `DSW12SL02` occurs nowhere in that document. You could ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select-Xml -xml $xml -XPath "//Computer" | 
  foreach { $_.node.Resource.split('/')[-1] }

549
550
552
551
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through each `Resource` attribute and extract the leaf item from the URL with [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7):

```
foreach ($url in $xml.BESAPI.Computer.Resource) {
    Split-Path -Path $url -Leaf
}
```

Or using [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) if you prefer using pipelines instead of `foreach` enumeration:

```
$xml.BESAPI.Computer.Resource | ForEach-Object {
    Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf
}
```

**Output:**

```
549
550
552
551
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7#parameters) for `-Leaf`:

> Indicates that this cmdlet returns only the last item or container in the path. For example, in the path C:\Test\Logs\Pass1.log, it returns only Pass1.log.

---

### Update

As [@Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657166/retrieve-xml-values-using-powershell/61658077?noredirect=1#comment109064639_61658077) mentioned in the comments, full URLs are not paths, so `Split-Path -Leaf` may run into issues.

A safer solution would be to convert the URL to a [`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1) object, then use the [`System.Uri.LocalPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.localpath?view=netcore-3.1#System_Uri_LocalPath) property instead:

```
foreach ($url in $xml.BESAPI.Computer.Resource) {
    Split-Path -Path ([uri]$url).LocalPath -Leaf
}
```

Or just use [`split`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html), similar to [js2010's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657166/retrieve-xml-values-using-powershell/61657730#61657730) answer:

```
foreach ($url in $xml.BESAPI.Computer.Resource) {
    ($url -split "/")[-1]
}
```

Comment: Full URLs are not paths, however. When passed through `Split-Path` with `-Leaf` you have a decent chance of things working, but it's still iffy. A simple string split seems more appropriate; if you *must* use `Split-Path` it'd be safer to work on `([uri] $url).LocalPath` instead.